# download image on android using http request in android

Tags: android

I have used a tutorial and arrived at this result which works in an emulator, but it ceases to work on a real Android device.

The code is given here and all other Android permissions required are set; internet and write to external device are set.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity {

    private final String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/";
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        DownloadFromUrl(PATH + "dwnldimg.png");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH  + "dwnldimg.png");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    public void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName) {
            try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.4/evilempire.jpg"); //you can write here any link
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    tv.setText("Starting download......from " + url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();;
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte) current);
                    }

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();
                    tv.setText("Download Completed in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 tv.setText("Error: " + e);
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your doing network operations on the main ui thread, which will result in a anr on pre-3.0 and a NetworkOnMainThreadException on 3.0+. Secondly I built [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime) which is a whole lot easier at loading remote images.

Answer (score 1):

Prime lib will help you, but to learn Android you need to know AsyncTask. Android have the UI Thread where the Activity runs, so if you do complicate operation that block the Android OS will throw a Force Close. 
So what you have to know is that if you need to do a download task or any operation that will eventually block the UI thread you can have to use Threads. The easy Android approach is AsyncTask.
I think this simple example will guide you to understand the AsyncTask.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html